# Converting between hex and float (IEEE 754) in TCL

Tags: floating-point, hex, tcl

Does TCL contain built in procedure to convert between a 32-bit or 64-bit hex value and its float or double representation respectively? Here I am from referring to conversion in both directions, into hex and from hex.

Comment: Looks like `format` (but not `scan`?) in 8.7 will support C's `%a` format for printing a float in hex. See https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/476.md

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `binary format` and `binary scan`:

```
binary scan [binary format f 3.14] H* hex
puts $hex; # c3f54840
binary scan [binary format d 3.14] H* hex
puts $hex; # 1f85eb51b81e0940
```

And for the reverse, use:

```
binary scan [binary format H* 1f85eb51b81e0940] d double
```

The f and d format specifiers will use the machine's native representation. If you need a specific endianness, use r or R for floats and q and Q for doubles. In both cases the lower case versions are for little-endian and the upper case versions are for big-endian.

So for little-endian hex to float:

```
binary scan [binary format H* c3f54840] r float
```

Comment: What is the difference between [binary format f 3.14] and [binary format d 3.14] ?

Comment: One's IEEE single precision (C `float`) and the other is IEEE double precision (C `double`).

Comment: f is for single precision (32-bit), d is for double precision (64-bit).

Comment: ok thanks, how do I use the r and q for the endiannes and what is H* ? I am not able to put r next to f or d.

Comment: You would use r instead of f, and q instead of d.

Comment: H* means: As many hex digits as available. See the binary manual page: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/binary.html